# LTspice voltage measurement

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ltspice

How do I measure voltage between two nodes when neither of them is ground? In the schematic below, I want to measure the voltage between nodes Vmic and Vx. Is it just (Vmic-Vx)? I'm afraid that gives a wrong answer.

[image]

Comment: related, possibly a duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204096/how-to-plot-voltage-drop-across-a-specific-component-in-ltspice/204097#204097

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.meas Vmicpk MAX(V(Vmic)-V(Vx))*1000`

> *Is it just (Vmic-Vx)?*

`Vmic` and `Vx` are node names and not voltages.

The voltages associated with each node are `V(Vmic)` and `V(Vx)`

The difference voltage between the two nodes is `V(Vmic)-V(Vx)`

Then multiply by 1000 if that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can also use V(Vmic,Vx).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, in LTspice you can identify in any command the voltage across two nodes with the syntax

```
V(node1,node2)
```

which in your case becomes

```
V(Vmic,Vx)
```

Comment: That will be useful for quick analysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use a differential voltage probe.

Click on the first node, and drag to the second node.

Comment: Nice. This can be used when viewing simulation window.